# Не перехватывает нажатие клавиши Enter в EditText

Tags: android

Код:

```
activityText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E){
                Log.d("edit", "setOnKeyListener: ");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Собственно:

```
event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER не перехватывается

event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 перехватывается

keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E перехватывается
```

Это тоже не срабатывает:

```
activityText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO){
                Log.d("edit", "setOnEditorActionListener: ");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Есть еще способы обработать нажатие Enter?

Comment: Посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext

Comment: Рабочий вариант:   
1. actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
2. в xml:
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:inputType="text"
android:singleLine="true"

Comment: мб просто неверный код кнопки? Если попроьбовать отдебажить и нажать ентер, перехватчик сработает (без условия)?

Comment: не срабатывает. 
activityText.setOnKeyListener ловит нажатия на буквы и цифры, но Enter нет. 
Легаси код.